# How many times am I iterating over the table while performing multiple column aggregations

Tags: sql

Say this is my query

`SELECT sum(colA * ColB) /sum(ColA), sum(ColA), avg(ColB) FROM TABLE`

How many times am I iterating over the table? Would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: what db system?

Comment: TLDR the table is only read once (assuming you don't use `DISTINCT` aggregation). Whether the same `SUM` is caclulated multiple times: almost certainly not.